# Solve integral $\iiint_Ax^pdxdydz$ on $A=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2<x^{\frac{1}{3}}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

We have following integral to count:
$$
\iiint_Ax^pdxdydz
$$
where $p$ is constant real number and $A=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2<x^{\frac{1}{3}}\}$

I tried spherical substitution and cylindrical.

Comment: I guess $x \geq 0$. Isn't it ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting $x=w^3$, the triple integral turns into
$$3\iiint_{w^6+y^2+z^2<w}w^{3p+2}\,dw\,dy\,dz \tag{1}$$
that equals:
$$ 3 \int_{0}^{1}\iint_{y^2+z^2<w-w^6}w^{3p+2}\,dy\,dz   \,dw\tag{2}$$
or:
$$ 3\pi \int_{0}^{1}w^{3p+2}(w-w^6)\,dw = \color{red}{\frac{5\pi}{(p+3)(3p+4)}}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: How did you move from (2) to (3)?

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk: $$\iint_{y^2+z^2<w-w^6}w^{3p+2}\,dy\,dz$$ is $w^{3p+2}$ times the area of a circle with squared radius $w-w^6$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
x^{p}\bracks{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} < x^{1/3}}\dd y\,\dd z\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{p}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{x^{2} + \rho^{2} < x^{1/3}}\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd\phi\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{p}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{\rho < x^{1/3} - x^{2}}\,\dd\rho\,\dd x =
\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{p}\bracks{x^{1/3} - x^{2} > 0}
\int_{0}^{x^{1/3}\ -\ x^{2}}\,\dd\rho\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{x^{p + 1/3} - x^{p + 2}}
\bracks{x < 1}\,\dd x =
\bbx{\ds{{5\pi \over \pars{3p + 4}\pars{p + 3}}\,,\qquad
\Re\pars{p} > -\,{4 \over 3}}}
\end{align}